# I need a word to combine three elements in any language

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word to combine water,air, and light into one word. It can be in any language. Just a word which means or implies water, light and air. Thank you

Comment: On this site, the answers must restrict themselves to English words (and established English words at that).

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element

Comment: **Dhaatu** in Hindi may be the word you are looking for. It means anything that occupies space. Water, earth or air

Comment: @KunalChitkara Or, presumably, fire? Fire also occupies space.

Comment: Do you mean 'liquid, gas or plasma'?  (Then the answer is 'fluid'.)  Did you mean to exclude 'earth/solid'?

Answer (score 2):

Element, elemental. From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/elemental):

> Elemental - 6. of, relating to, or of the nature of the four elements, earth, water, air, and fire, or of any one of them.

Comment: +1 I'd like to know how you know this. Can you add some reference?

Comment: @NVZ What is this 'elemental-6'? The OP only wants 3.

Comment: @Mitch Not my answer, but I think it means definition 6 in the dictionary.